# Android gcm project server key needs regeneration again and again

Tags: android, push-notification, key, google-cloud-messaging, api-key

For my android gcm project i created a new project on the console.developers.google.com and generated a server key which works fine for my app.But it works only until a specified time which was provided by google(i guess) for a server key for being active.

[image: servery key]

Now status for this api key is active until a specified time only.After that it won't work.Then i have to regenerate a key(or revert to obsolete key) then have to update that new key value in my server side php code in order to make it work.And the newly created key also has only 12-14 hours of active status.Then that key also won't work until i regenerate another key.

**Questions**

So do i have any other option except updating the new server key value in my server side code again and again?

Can a permanent server key be made which would remain active for a long time?If not,any other way we can deal with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a new server key, it doesn't have a an expiration date (i.e. you wouldn't see the Status line that says "Active until ...". It is permanent.

Therefore you can use the same server key for as long as you wish.

However, if you hit the "Regenerate Key" button, you can create a new key and make the old key obsolete. In this case you see the following message :

[image]

Once you hit "Replace key", the newly created key (shown in the top "API KEY" line) has no expiration date. The "Active until Aug 3 ..." is relevant only to the old "OBSOLETE KEY", which, as the message suggests, will be deactivated permanently in 24 hours.

Comment: Neat and Clear explanation.Got my answer.Thanks.